# Calculate shapes based on negative space created by other shapes within a container

Tags: php, math, shapes

This is more of a math question than anything else.

I work on book planning software in which advertisements can be placed on top of story pages. The story actually takes up 100% of the page, and ad shapes are placed on top of it.

[image]

The image on the left shows the page with just the story shape on it, before ads are placed.
The image on the right shows ads placed on top of the story shape.

My question in it’s most basic form is: **If I have the ad count, and the positioning and dimensions of all of the ads, how can I calculate the negative green space left over by the ads as individual shapes?** The ad count, positioning and dimensions can vary dramatically.

The reason I’m asking this is because after all ad shapes are placed, we allow the customer to “merge the page”. It then becomes a flat image. But I want to highlight the areas that are the “story” by placing a rectangle on top of them with a low opacity.

```
$layoutW = 6;
$layoutH = 8;

$adCount = 3;

$ad1[‘x’] = 0;
$ad1[‘y’] = 0;
$ad1[‘w’] = 2;
$ad1[‘h’] = 2;

$ad2[‘x’] = 2;
$ad2[‘y’] = 1;
$ad2[‘w’] = 4;
$ad2[‘h’] = 7;

$ad3[‘x’] = 0;
$ad3[‘y’] = 6;
$ad3[‘w’] = 2;
$ad3[‘h’] = 2;
```

Is what I am trying to achieve overly complicated? Any thoughts or insight is appreciated.